# Backbone.js view not rendering

Tags: javascript, oop, backbone.js

On my Backbone app, one of the views is not rendering as expected.

When a user follows the route 'test/addtests', it calls a function which is shown below

```
addtests: function () {

    this.testView = new TestView();
},
```

The view should then automatically render using the initialize function show below

```
window.TestView = Backbone.View.extend({

    template: _.template($('#test').html()),

    initialize: function () {
        tests.bind("reset", this.render, this);
    },

    render: function (eventName) {
        alert('asdf');
        $(this.el).html(this.template());
        _.each(tests.models, function (test) {
             this.renderSelectBox(test);
         }, this);
        return this;
    },

    renderSelectBox: function (test) {
           var optionView = new TFS.FormOptionView({
               model: test
           });
           $(this.el).append(optionView.render().el);
       },

    events:{
        "click button": "addTest"
    },

    ...ect

});
```

However nothing happens, it simply displays content from the last page. The alert I set up in the render function does not fire either. However oddly, if I click refresh, the alert fires :S.

The route is set up right, and correctly points to the 'addtests' function, it seems that it just is not initialising the view as expected.

Also a second thing I have found confusing is if I have a full collection, I am unable to use the get method to pull a single modle out. For example

```
players // a full collection

var test = players.get(1);

console.log(test.get('id')); //undefined
```

:S

Comment: the logical conclusion would be that the `reset` event within the view is not firing. How about adding an explicit call to `.render` before attaching your event handler?

Comment: Do you perhaps mean "`collection.bind("reset", this.render, this);`"?

Comment: no tests is a stored collection

Comment: good practice would be to do `this.testView = new TestView({collection: tests});` so that the view just minds its own business. The render is bound to the collection's reset event and the reset event is launched when the collection is fetched. So do you fetch the collection? No succesful fetch == no render!

Comment: thanks jakee, I will do that for better practise, I now have a problem, as the event does not fire, can anyone see a reason why the event would not fire!

Answer (score 0):

Whoops I was under the impression the bind function was calling render, but it seems that was not the case.

I just put

```
this.render();
```

in the views initialisation function and it worked.

Does anyone know why Im having trouble pulling a single module out of a collection sated above??